# How do you make a tkinter Listbox unselectable?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I was trying to make a program that has a constantly-cycling listbox, but I don't know how to configure the listbox in a way so that the user cannot interfere with it.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Totally unselectable? Have you tried configuring the state to be disabled? The listbox has many options controlling the state, the color of items in a state, and so on. Have you read through all of the documentation? It's not clear why you need our help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.